# Why does my jPlayer work in Firefox and not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jplayer

I'm making an audio player for my music blog that I run, but I can't seem to get jPlayer to work properly on my website. Right now, I have it set so that only admins can view the player (since it's not working), but I made a little test website so that you can see what I mean too.

The player works fine in Firefox, but won't work correctly on Chrome. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the flash fallback that it uses for Firefox, but I don't see why it wouldn't work on Chrome too. It just does not seem to want to load/stream the songs at all.

I have a few functions that I made so the songs can be added dynamically on whichever page you are viewing. I believe I am setting up everything correctly. I use an array for the title of the song and the URL to the MP3, and they are added dynamically by WordPress. Every time a new song is added, I call the JavaScript function add_song below...

```
function add_song(title, mp3)
{
    theTitles[index] = title;
    theMP3s[index] = mp3;
    index++;
}
```

Then for the document.ready function, I set up my jPlayer by using another function that I made called get_playlist();

```
function get_playlist()
{
    var playlist = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i < theTitles.length; i++)
    {
        playlist[i] = {title: theTitles[i], mp3: theMP3s[i]};
    }
    return playlist;
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var playlist = get_playlist();
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        oggSupport:false
    }, playlist, {
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```

I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple as to why it would work on Firefox and not Chrome, but I can't figure out what it is. If, however, you start to play one of the songs by pushing the play button on the actual post, then stop it, then try to play it in the top player, it works fine. For example, try to play the first song in the top player, it won't work. Then click the play button on the actual Seasfire post, pause it, then try on the top player again and it will work. Here is my [url](http://www.startingtofeelit.com/text.php) to the test site so you can view the player yourself if you have any questions.

Thanks guys and gals!

Comment: By the way, I know that the players look weird. I haven't messed with the look of the player or anything. I want to get the functionality working before I start on the aesthetics, so I know it looks bad/strange/broken.

Comment: I dont see `index` initialized or defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow won't let me log in right now, but I am the original poster.

index is defined and initialized before I use it, so that is not the problem. The whole javascript I use for that is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var index = 0;
    var theTitles = new Array();
    var theMP3s = new Array();

    function add_song(title, mp3)
    {
        theTitles[index] = title;
        theMP3s[index] = mp3;
        index++;
    }

    function get_playlist()
    {
        var playlist = new Array();

        for(var i = 0; i < theTitles.length; i++)
        {
            playlist[i] = {title: theTitles[i], mp3: theMP3s[i]};
        }
        return playlist;
    }


    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var playlist = get_playlist();
        new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, playlist, {
            swfPath: "/js",
            supplied: "mp3",
            wmode: "window"
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
```